# Lohstash Parser ERROR

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logparser

I want to parse the following JSON logs to elasticsearch / logshash. I have tried to parse it but unsuccessful. When I tried to parse it to logstash, it has shown `_jsonparsefailure` error, and shows some hexadecimal / different value instead of the data given in logs, as an output (message) [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq9aV.png).

LOG:

```
{
    "rows": [
        [18446738026507172656, "cmd.exe", 1644, 2528, 0, -1, 0, 0, "2017-10-08 10:19:10 UTC+0000", "2017-10-08 10:19:11 UTC+0000"]
    ],
    "columns": ["Offset(V)", "Name", "PID", "PPID", "Thds", "Hnds", "Sess", "Wow64", "Start", "Exit"]
}
```

## Used following parser:

```
input {
    tcp{
        port => 5043
        codec => "json"
     }
}

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
        index => "logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use json filter because input is already using JSON codec.

Remove JSON filter.